# How to convert list of bools to string? - Python 3.6.1

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, boolean

I am trying to convert list of bools to string, for example to convert `[False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]` to `'A'`

so how to do that (in python3)?

Comment: Is this your logic: [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True] => [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] => 01000001 binary => 65 decimal => A ???

Comment: Check the [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @R Sahu pointed out in the comments, do you mean something like this?

```
>>> lst = [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]
>>> binary = [1 if x else 0 for x in lst]
>>> bin_number = int("".join(map(str, binary)), 2)
>>> print(chr(bin_number))
A
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in my comment, I recommend using a proper module designed to work with bit lists like the [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) but if you want to do it yourself, here's a simple way:

```
bit_list = [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]
ascii_value = sum(v<<i for i, v in enumerate(reversed(bit_list)))
char_value = chr(ascii_value)
# A
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert you binary array to a string of bits and then convert it to an integer and then convert it to the character.

```
bits = [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]
print(chr(int(''.join("01"[a] for a in bits),2)))
```